# Adding rules to a dynamically created stylesheet inside a shadowDOM

Tags: css, web-component, shadow-dom

I recently started getting into WebComponents and I must say I have found it ground breaking so far! To get a better grasp of the concept, I am trying to adopt designs from my earlier project into reusable web components. I started by trying to create a Table element with some added features.

First of, I declared a minimal template for the component:

```
<template id="data-table-template">
  <table>
   <thead></thead>
   <tbody></tbody>
   <tfoot></tfoot>
  </table>
</template>
```

I use this template to create tables by taking table header values and row values as attributes. The element is used in the following manner:

```
<eur-data-table
  headers="getHeaders()",
  rowdata="getRowData()"
  host="#data-table-host"
  template="#data-table-template"
></eur-data-table>
```

In the component prototype `connectedCallback` method, I add the headers, rows and set style for the component. The generated shadow DOM fragment from Chrome Element inspector is as follows:

```
<eur-data-table headers="getHeaders()" ,="" rowdata="getRowData()" host="#data-table-host" template="#data-table-template" theme="firebrick">
<table>
 <style id="styleBlock"></style>
 <thead>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Age</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>Babu</td>
     <td>60</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Shyam</td>
     <td>35</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
</eur-data-table>
```

The problem lies in adding style rules. In the component class, I create a `style` element and I append it to the shadow DOM before adding rules to the `style.sheet` property. I checked the console output of `style.sheet` and it looks like all the rules were added. However, after inserting the style element to the shadow DOM, there are no rules as can be seen from the rendered output above.

In the component class, style is added in the following way:

```
connectedCallback() {
        let template = document.querySelector(DataTable._parseId(this.template));
        if(!template) throw new DOMException('Host and/or template ids are undefined');
        if(!this.hasAttribute('theme')) this.setAttribute('theme', 'firebrick');

        let style = document.createElement('style');
        style.setAttribute('id', 'styleBlock');
        // WebKit Hack
        style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(style);

        this._table = template.content.cloneNode(true);
        this._setupHeaders();
        this._setupBody();
        this._setupStyle(style.sheet); // style is not being applied!!
        console.dir(style.sheet); // logs a CSSStyleSheet object
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(this._table);
}
```

In the `connectedCallback` method, `_setupStyle` is passed a reference to the style sheet where, it adds the rules in the following manner (the rules are expressed as javascript object):

```
_setupStyle(sheet) {
   if(!sheet) throw new DOMException('sheet is undefined', 'StylesheetNotFoundException');
   let rules = window.themes[this.theme];
   if(!rules) throw new DOMException('Theme is undefined');

    Object.keys(rules)
       .sort((r1, r2) => rules[r1].order - rules[r2].order)
       .forEach(rule => {
           let o = _.omit(rules[rule], 'order');
           let i = rule.order;
           let s = this._makeRule(o, rule);
           sheet.insertRule(s, i);
       });    
}
```

The `order` value is an integer number used for sorting the style rules in order. Once sorted, the `order` key and its value is omitted from the object before converting it to a DOMString:

```
_makeRule(value, rule) {
    return `${rule} ${JSON.stringify(value).replace(new RegExp(/,/g), ';')}`;
}
```

Logging the `style.sheet` property prints:

```
CSSStyleSheet
cssRules: CSSRuleList
0: CSSStyleRule {selectorText: "tfoot", style: CSSStyleDeclaration, styleMap: StylePropertyMap, type: 1, cssText: "tfoot { }", …}
1: CSSStyleRule {selectorText: "tr:last-child > td", style: CSSStyleDeclaration, styleMap: StylePropertyMap, type: 1, cssText: "tr:last-child > td { }", …}
2: CSSStyleRule {selectorText: "td:last-child", style: CSSStyleDeclaration, styleMap: StylePropertyMap, type: 1, cssText: "td:last-child { }", …}
3: CSSStyleRule {selectorText: "td", style: CSSStyleDeclaration, styleMap: StylePropertyMap, type: 1, cssText: "td { }", …}
4: CSSStyleRule {selectorText: "tr:first-child", style: CSSStyleDeclaration, styleMap: StylePropertyMap, type: 1, cssText: "tr:first-child { }", …}
5: CSSStyleRule {selectorText: "tr:last-child", style: CSSStyleDeclaration, styleMap: StylePropertyMap, type: 1, cssText: "tr:last-child { }", …}
6: CSSStyleRule {selectorText: "tr", style: CSSStyleDeclaration, styleMap: StylePropertyMap, type: 1, cssText: "tr { }", …}
7: CSSStyleRule {selectorText: "th:last-child", style: CSSStyleDeclaration, styleMap: StylePropertyMap, type: 1, cssText: "th:last-child { }", …}
8: CSSStyleRule {selectorText: "th", style: CSSStyleDeclaration, styleMap: StylePropertyMap, type: 1, cssText: "th { }", …}
9: CSSStyleRule {selectorText: "thead", style: CSSStyleDeclaration, styleMap: StylePropertyMap, type: 1, cssText: "thead { }", …}
10: CSSStyleRule {selectorText: "thead tbody tfoot", style: CSSStyleDeclaration, styleMap: StylePropertyMap, type: 1, cssText: "thead tbody tfoot { }", …}
11: CSSStyleRule {selectorText: "table", style: CSSStyleDeclaration, styleMap: StylePropertyMap, type: 1, cssText: "table { }", …}
```

My question is: since the component gets rendered without error and since, I am adding all the rules as expected and attaching both, the style and table elements to the shadow DOM renders an element as expected then, why aren't my CSS rules being applied to the rendered content?

Answer (score 0):

for the time being, until the [shadow parts api](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-shadow-parts-1/) becomes available (which will allow us to declare whole elements as styleable by consumers)

i recommend using lots of [custom css properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) (style hooks) to provide a means for a consumer to influence the styling of your web components

there might be some polyfill support for a proposed property `adoptedStyleSheets` for the purposes of theming, but i've only seen it casually mentioned in some threads all rumor-like

Comment: If that's the case then it will be problem. The style rules uses the elements' names as selectors because of the encapsulation provided by shadow DOM. I know that custom properties gets leaked into shadow DOM and it would allow client to affect the style. But, as it is setup now, it will create problems namely name clashes with other rules (unless I find a way to make all rules as unique classes). So, just wondering if there's any chance at all that will allow me to add rules in the component class.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I finally found a working solution. it is much easier to add the style in the `innerHTML` property of the style tag. To do this, I needed to change the `_setupStyle` and `_makeRule` method (posted in the question) to the following:

```
_setupStyle(style) {
   if(!style) throw new DOMException('sheet is undefined', 'StylesheetNotFoundException');
   let rules = window.themes[this.theme];
   if(!rules) throw new DOMException('Theme is undefined');

   style.innerHTML = "";
   Object.keys(rules)
         .sort((r1, r2) => rules[r1].order - rules[r2].order)
         .forEach(rule => {
             let o = _.omit(rules[rule], 'order');
             let i = rule.order;
             let s = this._makeRule(o, rule);
             //sheet.insertRule(s, i);
             style.innerHTML += s + ' \n';
          });    
}
```

I am no longer using `CSSStyleSheet` class for adding rules (commented out); instead, I am just adding each rule on a new line. The `_makeRule` method is as follws:

```
_makeRule(value, rule) {
   return `${rule} ${JSON.stringify(value).replace(this._cssParseRule, ';').replace(/\'|\"/g, "")}`;
}
```

I modified the method to converted object into string and then replacing `,` with `;` followed by replacing all `'` or `"`. The rendered output is as follows:

```
<style id="styleBlock">
   table {border:1px solid firebrick;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0} 
   thead tbody tfoot {margin:0;padding:0} 
   thead {border-bottom:1px solid firebrick;background-color:firebrick;color:azure} 
   th {border-right:1px solid firebrick;border-bottom:1px solid firebrick} 
   th:last-child {border-bottom:none} 
   tr {margin:0;border-bottom:1px solid firebrick} 
   tr:last-child {border-bottom:none} 
   tr:first-child {border-left:none} 
   td {margin:0;padding:10px;text-align:center;border-left:1px solid firebrick;border-right:1px solid firebrick;border-bottom:1px solid firebrick} 
   td:last-child {border-right:none} 
   tr:last-child > td {border-bottom:none} 
   tfoot {margin:0;border-top:1px solid firebrick} 
</style>
```

Note: Although the CSS is working, it is not correct; there should be a `;` at the end of the last property for each rule.